# CIFilters directly on OpenGL texture

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl, core-image

How can I apply CIFilters directly on OpenGL texture? To avoid VRAM->RAM->VRAM (GPU->CPU->GPU) actions. I mean to avoid this type of pipeline:

[image]

Because they are slow. I need somehow to do as much as possible in GPU. But how?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [CGBitmapContextCreate()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html)

```
CGContextRef CGBitmapContextCreate (
   void *data,
   size_t width,
   size_t height,
   size_t bitsPerComponent,
   size_t bytesPerRow,
   CGColorSpaceRef colorspace,
   CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo
);
```

Notice that it takes void *data. This can be your image data which you can pass directly to OpenGL.

Comment: And how then to get CGContextRef directly to CIFilter and back? Maby I should use `imageWithTexture:size:flipped:colorSpace:` to get CIImage from texture, then apply CIFilter and somehow convert back to texture? But how?

Comment: You dont have to get CGContextRef, you already have it. void *data you passed in CGBitmapContextCreate() is your image buffer. Anything operation you do on that data is indirectly on image. Makes sense?